# Event Trigger for window process

Tags: c#, mfc

**What I want to do:**
I have a process "abc.exe" that I want my application to trigger an event when the RAM memory or cpu for this process exceed certain value.

I know how to do this using PerformanceCounter in C# but it is very manual, I have to create a timer and read in the counter for RAM and CPU.

```
        foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "% Committed Bytes In Use", p.ProcessName);

            try
            {
                PerformanceCounter myAppCpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", p.ProcessName, true);
                myAppCpu.NextValue();
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                Program.ProcessList.Add(
                new ProcessInfo(
                    p.MainModule.ModuleName,
                    p.Id,
                    p.HandleCount,
                    myAppCpu.NextValue(),
                    p.PrivateMemorySize64,              //PrivateMemorySize:  The number of bytes that the associated process has allocated that cannot be shared with other processes.
                    p.WorkingSet64,
                    p.PeakVirtualMemorySize64,          //PeakVirtualMemorySize:  The maximum amount of virtual memory that the process has requested.
                    p.PeakPagedMemorySize64,            //PeakPagedMemorySize:  The maximum amount of memory that the associated process has allocated that could be written to the virtual paging file.
                    p.PagedSystemMemorySize64,          //PagedSystemMemorySize:  The amount of memory that the system has allocated on behalf of the associated process that can be written to the virtual memory paging file.
                    p.PagedMemorySize64,                //PagedMemorySize:  The amount of memory that the associated process has allocated that can be written to the virtual memory paging file.
                    p.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64));     //NonpagedSystemMemorySize:  The amount of memory that the system has allocated on behalf of the associated process that cannot be written to the virtual memory paging file.

            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
```

However, this is not very ideal since I have to constantly run it.  Does MFC, C# or window provide a way I can tap in to some sort of event and subscribe to this kind of event for each process?

Comment: In the beginning you say "**a**" process and at the end you say "**each**" process so it is not clear what you want to do. I suggest using a timer instead of Sleep.

Comment: great suggestion on the timer instead of sleep.  My end goal is to be able to track any threshold change of one or multiple process..let's say if I want to track proc1.exe, proc2.exe...ect... an event can fire if any of them exceed 200MB for example.

Comment: So do you want to be notified of a relevant event without needing to poll (check periodically) for it? Are you familiar with WMI and the System.Management namespace? It will probably help somehow.